# Start marquee effect on an element if the orientation changes to landscape using css media queries

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

How do I tart marquee effect on an html element if the orientation changes to landscape using css media queries only (no javascript).
I can change the background like and font style like this

```
    @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    p {
       font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       font-weight:bold
      }
```

***How do i go about the marquee effect?***

Comment: marquee is a tag which isn't supported anymore. Since you tagged your question with jquery, are you using their marquee functionality? If so, you will need to enable the marquee effect anyways with javascript. If you want a css solution you could duplicate your p and only show one or the other depending on the orientation.

Comment: You could use keyframe animation set to loop infinitely and within that, transition the text using translateX(100%) to translateX(-100%). You won't be able to do anything clever like pausing the effect without JavaScript, though.

Comment: Here's a page with some examples: https://www.quackit.com/css/codes/marquees/ - I would recommend following one of those and then post back if you have any specific issues.

Comment: Thank you!! Both of your solutions work like a charm!!